# Change value of certain rows of a column data frame: taxonomic table

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a taxonomic table (data frame) that consists of a number of bacteria observations with assignations to different taxonomical levels (5 columns for the 5 taxonomical levels, which are termed Ranks). Some observations don´t have the full assignation which means that there is missing information, and these observations need to get filled with the letter of the taxonomical level and _. 
I need to fill the rows which have the missing information for a certain column with a string.

A subset of what I have is (Rank 5 has missing info):

```
     tax_table_F[51:59,]
             Rank1             Rank2                  Rank3              Rank4                      Rank5
    214036             k__Bacteria     p__Firmicutes          c__Clostridia   o__Clostridiales      f__[Mogibacteriaceae]
    968675             k__Bacteria p__Proteobacteria c__Gammaproteobacteria  o__Pasteurellales         f__Pasteurellaceae
    121873             k__Bacteria     p__Firmicutes          c__Clostridia   o__Clostridiales      f__Dehalobacteriaceae
    357046             k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes         c__Bacteroidia   o__Bacteroidales           f__Rikenellaceae
    302106             k__Bacteria  p__Synergistetes         c__Synergistia   o__Synergistales f__Dethiosulfovibrionaceae
    836693             k__Bacteria     p__Firmicutes          c__Clostridia          o__SHA-98                        f__
    577170             k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes         c__Bacteroidia   o__Bacteroidales          f__Bacteroidaceae
    269386             k__Bacteria  p__Cyanobacteria              c__4C0d-2             o__YS2                        f__
    New.ReferenceOTU79 k__Bacteria     p__Firmicutes             c__Bacilli o__Lactobacillales        f__Lactobacillaceae
```

What I wish to do is replace the Observations in the Rank5 column that have "f__" with a concatenation of the data from the columns Rank3, Rank4 and Rank5.

What I have done is create a new data frame tax_table_sF, subsetting all the Observations that have "f__" (manually by the rowname) and replace the Rank5 data with the concatenated information from the 3 columns.

```
tax_table_sF<-tax_tableF[c(1887417 ,461487, 360268, 211720 , 467605, 290455, 836693 , 269386 , "OTU38251" ),] # generate the new data frame

tax_table_sF$Rank5<-paste(tax_table_sF$Rank3, tax_table_sF$Rank4, tax_table_sF$Rank5, sep=".") # replace "f__" with concatenated data

                                                Rank1             Rank2                  Rank3            Rank4
            1887417                       k__Bacteria            p__TM7               c__TM7-3              o__
            461487                        k__Bacteria     p__Firmicutes          c__Clostridia o__Clostridiales
            360268                        k__Bacteria    p__Tenericutes                 c__RF3     o__ML615J-28
            211720                        k__Bacteria p__Proteobacteria c__Alphaproteobacteria          o__RF32
            467605                        k__Bacteria  p__Cyanobacteria         c__Chloroplast  o__Streptophyta
            290455                        k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes         c__Bacteroidia o__Bacteroidales
            836693                        k__Bacteria     p__Firmicutes          c__Clostridia        o__SHA-98
            269386                        k__Bacteria  p__Cyanobacteria              c__4C0d-2           o__YS2
           OTU38251 k__Bacteria    p__Tenericutes          c__Mollicutes          o__RF39
                                                                        Rank5
            1887417                                          c__TM7-3.o__.f__
            461487                         c__Clostridia.o__Clostridiales.f__
            360268                                    c__RF3.o__ML615J-28.f__
            211720                         c__Alphaproteobacteria.o__RF32.f__
            467605                         c__Chloroplast.o__Streptophyta.f__
            290455                        c__Bacteroidia.o__Bacteroidales.f__
            836693                                c__Clostridia.o__SHA-98.f__
            269386                                       c__4C0d-2.o__YS2.f__
           OTU38251           c__Mollicutes.o__RF39.f__
```

then I tried,

```
tax_table_F_mer<-merge(tax_table_F., tax_table_sF)
```

but I get a empty data frame. I tried adding `by="Rank5"` or adding a new column `df$rowname<-rownames(df)` and adding `by="rownames"`
without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's quick dirty example (I hope I understand what you want to achieve):

```
tax_table_F[tax_table_F$Rank5=="f__",]$Rank5 <- cbind(paste(tax_table_F[tax_table_F$Rank5=="f__",]$Rank3,tax_table_F[tax_table_F$Rank5=="f__",]$Rank4,tax_table_F[tax_table_F$Rank5=="f__",]$Rank5,sep="."))
```

Comment: When I run the paste(tax...) it gives a vector of strings with the combinations I want but the cbind command fails because it fills the data frame with NA. It says Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c("c__TM7-3.o__.f__", "c__Clostridia.o__Clostridiales.f__",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated.

Comment: thats because it seems Rank5 is factor.  You can convert Rank5 to character and then it should work.  e.g. tax_table_F$Rank5=as.character(tax_table_F$Rank5)

Comment: In deed it was a factor and changing it to a character, made it work perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as previous one but code may be a bit more readable

```
tax_table_F$Rank5 <- as.character(tax_table_F$Rank5)    # as necessary, convert column from factor to character
f__rows <- tax_table_F$Rank5=="f__"       #  rows to be changed              
tax_table_F$Rank5[f__rows ] <- with(tax_table_F[f__rows,], paste(Rank3, Rank4, Rank5, sep="." ) )
```